# How to add appropriate image size width and height in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have models for image and upload image, how to generate size width and height in django?

`article/models.py`

```
class article(models.model):
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
```

`code head.html`

````
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ article.image1 }}" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{{ article.image1 }}" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content=" " />
<meta property="og:image:height" content=" " />```
````

add size height and width generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my **models.py**

```
class article(models.model):
image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', width_field='image1_width', height_field='image1_height')
image1_width = models.IntegerField(editable=False, null=True)
image1_height = models.IntegerField(editable=False, null=True)
```

my code head.html

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ article.image1 }}" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{{ article.image1 }}" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="{{ article.image1_width }}" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="{{ article.image1_height }}" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Django `ImageField` has a built-in feature for this. You just need to add two new columns for width and height:

```py
class article(models.model):
    image1 = models.ImageField(width_field='image1_width', height_field='image1_height', upload_to='images', blank=True)
    image1_width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    image1_height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then you can simply do:

````html
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ article.image1 }}" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{{ article.image1 }}" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="{{ article.image1_width }}" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="{{ article.image1_height }}" />```
````